# 'Espresso' Maker - Base turned dark, is it bad?

Tags: coffee, espresso, aluminum-cookware

A few days ago I got an 'Espresso' maker made out of Aluminium (one of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000CNY6UK)).
At the moment I am experimenting a bit with it, but I noticed something strange. The base (the part where you put the water in) turned dark from the inside. Is this normal or bad, maybe even dangerous? Do I need to clean it? If so: How do I clean it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got there, is a Moka pot. They are unable to produce the amount of pressure that gives the Espresso its character, in particular the crema.

I have owned several, and all of them have had this happen. That has had no impact on the flavour or mouth feel.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I know that they don't make real Espresso, thats why I've written 'Espresso' wrapped in quotation marks ;-)

Comment: Oh, absolutely, I assumed as much. Still, I thought it was worthwhile to point it out for the benefit of other users, who may or may not know the peculiars.